# Sencha and Java Servlet sync()

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am adapting a tutorial to change from localstorage to use a java servlet but i am having some problems.  I am trying to update the changes a user makes by calling sync() but i am getting these errors.

```
[WARN][Ext.data.Operation#process] Unable to match the record that came back from the server.
```

I tried seeing if the updated values where being send to the servlet

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

is null.  How do I send the updated values back the server and read them? I tried looking for a sencha touch + servlets tutorial but can't find anything

this is my sync code

```
var showsStore = Ext.getStore("Shows");

    if (null == showsStore.findRecord('name', currentShow.data.name)) {
        showsStore.add(currentShow);
    }

    showsStore.sync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your data store

```
 writer: {
         type: 'json',
         rootProperty: 'data',
         encode: true,
         writeAllFields: true
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected return for a store sync is an array of JSON records, or nothing.

Comment: ya a jsonarray is returned. the same one that was sent before. The updated values from the edittext fields are not being sent to my server